# php Code working offline but not online

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, google-visualization

I am facing a problem whilst calling a php script that uses sql to query a MySQL database. The code is working offline but when I upload to the server, the code loops through 5 times and returns a strange json string. I've checked the sql in phpMyAdmin and it returns the correct values.

I'm calling the script using the following javascript:

```
            var jsonData1 = $.ajax({
                url: "php/ResidualArisingsdata.php?PrimaryKey=<?php echo $primarykey ?>",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false
            }).responseText;
```

and the php script is (with login details removed)

```
<?php 
    $_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $primarykey = $_GET['PrimaryKey'];    

// These variables define the connection information for your MySQL database 
    $username = "xxx"; 
    $password = "xxx"; 
    $host = "localhost"; 
    $dbname = "xxx"; 

    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
    }

    $SQLString = "SELECT PrimaryKey,
        Name,
        `HouseholdRecyclingRate2005/06`,
        `HouseholdRecyclingRate2006/07`,
        `HouseholdRecyclingRate2007/08`,
        `HouseholdRecyclingRate2008/09`,
        `HouseholdRecyclingRate2009/10`,
        `HouseholdRecyclingRate2010/11`,
        `HouseholdRecyclingRate2011/12`
        FROM `districts_recyclingrates`
        WHERE `districts_recyclingrates`.PrimaryKey =" . $primarykey;       

    $result = $mysqli->query($SQLString); 

    $rows = array();
    $table = array();
    $table['cols'] = array(
        array('label' => 'Year', 'type' => 'string'),
        array('label' => 'Name', 'type' => 'number'),
        array('label' => 'UK Average', 'type' => 'number')
    );

    foreach($result as $r) {
    $temp = array();


    $temp[] = array('v' => "05/06"); 
    $temp[] = array('v' =>(int) $r['`HouseholdRecyclingRate2005/06`']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => "25.2"); 
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    unset($temp);
    $temp[] = array('v' => "06/07"); 
    $temp[] = array('v' =>(int) $r['HouseholdRecyclingRate2006/07']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => "29.7");
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    unset($temp);
    $temp[] = array('v' => "07/08"); 
    $temp[] = array('v' =>(int) $r['HouseholdRecyclingRate2007/08']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => "33.6");
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    unset($temp);
    $temp[] = array('v' => "08/09"); 
    $temp[] = array('v' =>(int) $r['HouseholdRecyclingRate2008/09']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => "36.4");
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    unset($temp);
    $temp[] = array('v' => "09/10"); 
    $temp[] = array('v' =>(int) $r['HouseholdRecyclingRate2009/10']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => "38.2");
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    unset($temp);
    $temp[] = array('v' => "10/11"); 
    $temp[] = array('v' =>(int) $r['HouseholdRecyclingRate2010/11']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => "40.3");
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    unset($temp);
    $temp[] = array('v' => "11/12"); 
    $temp[] = array('v' =>(int) $r['HouseholdRecyclingRate2011/12']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => "42.1");
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    }

    $table['rows'] = $rows;
    // convert data into JSON format
    $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
    echo $jsonTable;

    mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

The returned json (identified with console.log) looks like the following where the database values are 0 and the foreach has looped through 5 times.

```
{"cols":[{"label":"Year","type":"string"},{"label":"Name","type":"number"},{"label":"UK Average","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"05\/06"},{"v":0},{"v":"25.2"}]},{"c":[{"v":"06\/07"},{"v":0},{"v":"29.7"}]},{"c":[{"v":"07\/08"},{"v":0},{"v":"33.6"}]},{"c":[{"v":"08\/09"},{"v":0},{"v":"36.4"}]},{"c":[{"v":"09\/10"},{"v":0},{"v":"38.2"}]},{"c":[{"v":"10\/11"},{"v":0},{"v":"40.3"}]},{"c":[{"v":"11\/12"},{"v":0},{"v":"42.1"}]},{"c":[{"v":"05\/06"},{"v":0},{"v":"25.2"}]},{"c":[{"v":"06\/07"},{"v":0},{"v":"29.7"}]},{"c":[{"v":"07\/08"},{"v":0},{"v":"33.6"}]},{"c":[{"v":"08\/09"},{"v":0},{"v":"36.4"}]},{"c":[{"v":"09\/10"},{"v":0},{"v":"38.2"}]},{"c":[{"v":"10\/11"},{"v":0},{"v":"40.3"}]},{"c":[{"v":"11\/12"},{"v":0},{"v":"42.1"}]},{"c":[{"v":"05\/06"},{"v":0},{"v":"25.2"}]},{"c":[{"v":"06\/07"},{"v":0},{"v":"29.7"}]},{"c":[{"v":"07\/08"},{"v":0},{"v":"33.6"}]},{"c":[{"v":"08\/09"},{"v":0},{"v":"36.4"}]},{"c":[{"v":"09\/10"},{"v":0},{"v":"38.2"}]},{"c":[{"v":"10\/11"},{"v":0},{"v":"40.3"}]},{"c":[{"v":"11\/12"},{"v":0},{"v":"42.1"}]},{"c":[{"v":"05\/06"},{"v":0},{"v":"25.2"}]},{"c":[{"v":"06\/07"},{"v":0},{"v":"29.7"}]},{"c":[{"v":"07\/08"},{"v":0},{"v":"33.6"}]},{"c":[{"v":"08\/09"},{"v":0},{"v":"36.4"}]},{"c":[{"v":"09\/10"},{"v":0},{"v":"38.2"}]},{"c":[{"v":"10\/11"},{"v":0},{"v":"40.3"}]},{"c":[{"v":"11\/12"},{"v":0},{"v":"42.1"}]},{"c":[{"v":"05\/06"},{"v":0},{"v":"25.2"}]},{"c":[{"v":"06\/07"},{"v":0},{"v":"29.7"}]},{"c":[{"v":"07\/08"},{"v":0},{"v":"33.6"}]},{"c":[{"v":"08\/09"},{"v":0},{"v":"36.4"}]},{"c":[{"v":"09\/10"},{"v":0},{"v":"38.2"}]},{"c":[{"v":"10\/11"},{"v":0},{"v":"40.3"}]},{"c":[{"v":"11\/12"},{"v":0},{"v":"42.1"}]}]}
```

Would appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$temp = array();` should be outside your `foreach()` loop.

Comment: @Ben - not when it also gets unset inside the loop (but not re-created!). There is so much wrong with this question, the code and the database I don't know where to start!

Comment: @user24....: you might want to start by posting your code at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and reading http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks. I have tried but it doesn't make any difference to the json output.

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **Never** use string interpolation to accomplish this. `$primarykey` is pulled directly from `$_GET` and injected into your query, creating a serious problem here.

Comment: Any idea why the code works offline but not online?

Comment: The only reason it would loop through the `foreach` loop 5 times is if `$result` contains 5 rows of data.  Inspect the contents of `$results` to confirm with `var_dump($results);`.  +1 for the security issues noted by others here, lest ye be exposed to the [Bobby Drop Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can debug JSON errors in php with [json_last_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) function.

An example would be:

```
<?php
// An invalid UTF8 sequence
$text = "\xB1\x31";

$json  = json_encode($text);
$error = json_last_error();

var_dump($json, $error === JSON_ERROR_UTF8);
?>
```

**Anyway, you have an information security flaws in you're code the first one called XSS (Cross site Scripting).**

which is located in you'r javascript code, this line:

> url: "php/ResidualArisingsdata.php?PrimaryKey=",

You are printing an unvalidated input from the user, read about it at:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

And the second flaw is SQL injection, you include an unvalidated input from the user into you'r SQL query, this is very dangerous thing to do, read about it here: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Could you give me an idea of why the code is looping through five times please? I will sort out the security errors when this is sorted.